# R hts group level forecast

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm using R `hts` package which gives amazing functionalities in hierarchical forecast.

My problem is when I used `gts` function with four levels 
`gts <- gts(x, characters=list(2,2,3,3))` and when I checked the 
`gts$labels`

it gives me only from `G1` to `G10`

which includes only the individual level time series and two combined and couldn't find the combination of three levels.

Comment: It appears you are trying to construct a non-hierarchical grouped time series with four grouping variables. Correct? Without the column names of `x` there is nothing much that can be said to help. You might find example 3 in `help(hts::gts)` helpful.